# batch - execute command for every file with specific creation date

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

got this piece of code:

```
forfiles /P %ParentFolder% /S /M %Format% /C "cmd /c %exeFile% @path"
```

executing some exe for every file matching format as parameter.

**any way to add "creation date" as a condition to run command via CMD?**

something like :

*for all files in directory (recursive) X if creation date newer then 1 day ago do (run) some exe with this file's path as param*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with `forfiles`, because, when the `/D` option is provided, it only regards the last modification date only (not even the modification time).

Unfortunately, there are no native commands for date/time maths, so I suggest to switch to a language that is capable of that; for instance, PowerShell, VBScript, JavaScript (which are all native to Windows past XP).

In case the modification date could be used, and a simple check with the date of today is sufficient, the following `forfiles` command line could be used:

```
forfiles /S /P "%ParentFolder%" /M "%Format%" /D +0 /C "cmd /C \"%exeFile%\" @path"
```

The `/D` option with a non-negative number lets `forfiles` return files that have been modified the given number of days after today or later (although you would need a time-machine; hence I consider this a design flaw). For `+0` as the given number of days, all matching files modified today are returned, because `forfiles /D` only checks the modification date but does not care about the modification time.

---

If a simple equality check of the creation date with the date of today is fine for you, it can be done in [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) scripting quite easily though (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks for how the following script works):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "ParentFolder=."
set "Format=*.*"
set "exeFile=" & rem // (full path to executable file)
set "tmpFile=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"

rem // Create a temporary file and retrieve its creation date:
2> nul del "%tmpFile%" & > "%tmpFile%" break & set "TODAY="
for /F "skip=5" %%J in ('dir /N /4 /-C /T:C "%tmpFile%"') do (
    if not defined TODAY set "TODAY=%%J" & del "%tmpFile%"
)

rem // Change to predefined parent directory:
pushd "%ParentFolder%" && (
    rem // Return all files recursively:
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /S /A:-D "%Format%"') do (
        rem // Determine the creation date for the current file:
        set "FIRST=#"
        for /F "skip=5" %%J in ('dir /N /-C /T:C "%%I"') do (
            rem // Regard line listing file only, ignore summary lines:
            if defined FIRST (
                set "FIRST="
                rem // Check creation date against today:
                if "%%J"=="%TODAY%" (
                    rem // Return files created today:
                    echo "%%I" has been created today.
                    rem // Run external program on found file:
                    if defined exeFile "%exeFile%" "%%I"
                )
            )
        )
    )
    rem // Restore previous working directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

I am using two `dir` command lines here:

1. the first one returns a bare list of files recursively (`/S`; no directories because of `/A:-D`) without any dates/times, headers and footers, due to switch `/B`; not using this switch would lead to header and footer lines for the whole output and for every iterated sub-directory also, so the output would be quite complicated to be parsed;
2. the second one receives each file returned by the first one; since there is no `/B` but the `/N` option, the file creation date/time is returned (`/T:C`); for every file the output looks like this:

   > ```
   >  Volume in drive D is DATA
   >  Volume Serial Number is 0000-0000
   >
   >  Directory of D:\Data
   >
   > 2016/09/29  16:00               1024 current_file.txt
   >                1 File(s)           1024 bytes
   >                0 Dir(s)   1099511623680 bytes free
   > ```

   the first token of the sixth line constituting the creation date is split off and compared against the current date `%DATE%`; to ignore the header, the `skip=5` option of the `for /F` loop is used; to ignore the summary lines, the variable `FIRST` is used;

Note that the date format is locale-dependent; as long as there appear no spaces in the date, this is no problem as the current date is also determined by the `dir` command applied on a temporary file.

Comment: its a magic !! thank you for your time invested in such great answer. got a little problem with if "%%J"=="%DATE%". the date return actual day in week in addition to date - day dd:mm:yyyy while %%J dd:mm:yyyy. fixed it with set "nowDate=%DATE:~4,10%" at the top and if "%%J"=="%nowDate%". can you add to answer? or maybe there is much elegant approach?

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about the day prefix (which also depends on your system settings)... What is the output of `date /T`? does it also include the weekday?

Comment: `Sun` -- that is what I meant with "weekday" (sorry for not being clear enough)... Your solution using `nowDate` is fine for your date format, but it fails for others; I try to find something more general and update my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `forfiles /?` shows the switch `/D` that will exclude files that are younger (`/d -<days>`) or older (`/d +<days>`) than the given value for `<days>`.

As you want the files from today, you would set `<date>` to 0.

Notice, that this will look on the **changed date**!

Other way would be to use a `for /r`-loop and get a list of the creation date with `dir /T:C` ; to sort it add `/O-D`. Then separate that using a `for /f` loop to get the lines of the output of `dir` and another one to separate it (possibly easier without the nested loops).

You can than compare the *creation* date with `%date%` or when using one day=24 hrs compare the *creation* time with `%time%` additionally.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but D is for "Modified" field.

Comment: As written... Added another way, that might get complicated, but that would be how I would make it, I guess.

Comment: Regard that `forfiles`, when using option `/D +<days>`, returns files modified `<days>` days *after* today's date (I consider this a design flaw as you would need a time machine to find matching files)...